# download chart as jpg instead of png

Tags: javascript, chartkick

I find [react-chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/react-chartkick) (based on [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick)) very useful and easy for integration.

I use also its [download-charts](https://github.com/ankane/react-chartkick#download-charts) feature.

The only problem is that I have to provide a way to download the chart as jpg image and it looks like there is no such an option (it always creates a png file). Am I missing anything? Any idea for solution?

[Here](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/458) is the issue I've opened on GitHub.

Comment: Usually graphs and flat color images should be in .PNG as the quality can be preserved in a smaller image size. On the other hand you can always apply a transformation to your file with another tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the filename in the `download` option.

```
{download: "chart.jpg"}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9k3tLo1/) for usage.

Comment: Nice try, but incorrect answer. It's still png (the computer checks the headers inside the file, finds out that it's png and opens it as png). You can open it with notepad/vi and check the headers or use one of the online tools, for example http://checkfiletype.com. You will see that it's still png.